# Warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class(org.ksoap2.transport.KeepAliveHttpsTransportSE$1)

Tags: android, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ksoap

When compiling an Android project with `ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar` as a referenced library (external jar) I get this warning:

```
[2012-03-20 11:50:50 - AddressBook] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.ksoap2.transport.KeepAliveHttpsTransportSE$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
```

I'm trying to access EWS SOAP services from an android client and my code is:

```
String NAMESPACE = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages";

String SOAP_ACTION = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages";
String METHOD_NAME = "GetUserAvailability";
String URL = "https://vpnqrd0302.outlook.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx";

        String result = null;
        Object resultRequestSOAP = null;

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;


        List<HeaderProperty> headerList = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
        headerList.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Basic "
                + org.kobjects.base64.Base64
                .encode("temp@tempsuer.onmicrosoft.com:Password1"
                                .getBytes())));

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope, headerList);

            String requestDumpString = androidHttpTransport.requestDump;
            System.out.println("requestDump : " + requestDumpString);


            resultRequestSOAP = envelope.getResponse(); // Output received

            System.out.println("resultRequestSOAP : " + resultRequestSOAP);

            result = resultRequestSOAP.toString(); // Result string

            System.out.println("OUTPUT : " + result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And the error is:

```
03-20 12:21:16.488: W/System.err(7919): SoapFault - faultcode: 'a:ErrorSchemaValidation' faultstring: 'The request failed schema validation: Could not find schema information for the element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages:GetUserAvailability'.' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@4801ce80
03-20 12:21:16.491: W/System.err(7919):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:136)
03-20 12:21:16.491: W/System.err(7919):     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:137)
03-20 12:21:16.495: W/System.err(7919):     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:96)
03-20 12:21:16.495: W/System.err(7919):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:189)
03-20 12:21:16.499: W/System.err(7919):     at net.vivekiyer.GAL.ActiveSyncManager.getUserAvailabilityRequest(ActiveSyncManager.java:978)
03-20 12:21:16.499: W/System.err(7919):     at net.vivekiyer.GAL.CorporateAddressBook$GALSearch.doInBackground(CorporateAddressBook.java:510)
03-20 12:21:16.507: W/System.err(7919):     at net.vivekiyer.GAL.CorporateAddressBook$GALSearch.doInBackground(CorporateAddressBook.java:1)
03-20 12:21:16.507: W/System.err(7919):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
03-20 12:21:16.507: W/System.err(7919):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-20 12:21:16.511: W/System.err(7919):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-20 12:21:16.511: W/System.err(7919):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
03-20 12:21:16.511: W/System.err(7919):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
03-20 12:21:16.515: W/System.err(7919):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Comment: I see this and the usual answer is to ignore inner class warning as this is a result of including jar files.  Although in your case you might want to grab the source and compile it into your code.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but in case anyone stumbles here like I did: the warning you mention is caused by an anonymous inner class and the fact that ksoap2 is compiled with java 1.3 compatibility (for compatibility with J2ME I think). This warning can be safely ignored unless you are doing some reflective work on those classes (and even in that case: only if you are checking for the fact that a class is an inner class).

What's better is that this particular warning was fixed wih release 2.6.4 of ksoap2-android (see [this pull request on github](https://github.com/mosabua/ksoap2-android/pull/16)).

Your error is completely unrelated and is more likely caused by an incorrect use of the webservice you're trying to call.